# Error Uninstall SMB1

Tags: windows-server-2016, server-message-block, programsandfeatures

I tried to execute this command in powershell

```
Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name FS-SMB1 -Remove
```

but encountered error message

> Uninstall-WindowsFeature: The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed. Removal of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701

I executed this command

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name FS-SMB1
```

and the output is

```
Display Name                                Name                Install State
-------------                               ------              ---------------
[X] SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support       FS-SMB1             Installed
```

Please help.. I am using Windows Server 2016

Comment: `Get-WindowsFeature` does not install Windows features, it only lists them. As long as you didn't run `Install-WindowsFeature` it shouldn't be installed. Could you edit the output of the command `Get-WindowsFeature -Name FS-SMB1` into your question as well?

Comment: Yes, Get-WindowsFeature help me to confirmed that the SMB1 is installed on my server. I will edit the output of Get-WindowsFeature -Name FS-SMB1

Comment: Did you reboot the server first, if there was any updates pending restart? Did you run PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I reboot the server a few times. Yes, I rrun the Powershell with Administrator rights